# How to select entire row by distinct column MVC code first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a table called "Vehicles" with a numerous amount of columns. One of the columns being "Group". Multiple vehicles in the "Vehicles" table may have the same "Group"

I would like to select all the first records in the "Vehicles" table by Distinct "Group".

So basically I would like to write a query to pull out all Distinct "Groups" along with the entire record and add these to a list.

I am using the code first approach for my queries like below,

(Example)

`db.Locations.Select(x => x.location_name).Distinct();`

Is there a way to do this? Or would it be simpler using a different query style?

Answer (score 0):

```
db.Vehicles.GroupBy(x => x.Group).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```